# ASP.Net Core - Toast notification not showing on deployed application

Tags: asp.net-core, iis, toast

I made a few applications using aspnet core (version 2.0 and 2.2) and i added a server side notification using toastr (i used [this](https://github.com/nabinked/NToastNotify) plugin and followed the guide as shown in the link to pop up the notifications). Everything works fine when i debug using visual studio, but when i deploy the application the notifications never pop up and i don't have any feedback. Is there an application pool configuration or setting somewhere to make them work as in local environment?

I would show you some code, but it's pretty much the same as the guide i followed. In case of need, tell me if i have to show you some code or anything else. Thanks in advance

Comment: Did you check in the browser console? any error there?

Comment: @Div nope, no error in there

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I actually found a solution to my problem. In the `startup.cs` file in the Configure method, it's apparently necessary put `app.UseCookiePolicy();` method AFTER `app.UseMvc` and the notification work like a charm. I still don't understand why in my local PC the notification worked anyway.

Comment: Thanks for this answer. Saved me a lot of time and effort.

Answer (score 0):

```
webBuilder.ConfigureAppConfiguration((ctx, cb) =>
{
   StaticWebAssetsLoader.UseStaticWebAssets(
   ctx.HostingEnvironment,
   ctx.Configuration);

});  try it in program.cs
```